# When using CONTour options in ROOT's THistPainter class, how to add a colour scale?

Tags: c++, root-framework

I currently have the coding to create a CONT plot from an inputted set of data

```
 const int NbinX = 45; 
 const double binXlow = 0.0; 
 const double binXhigh = 2.0;

 const int NbinY = 45; 
 const double binYlow = 0.0; 
 const double binYhigh = 200.0;


 TH2D* hist3 = new TH2D("hist", "hist", NbinX, binXlow, binXhigh, NbinY, binYlow, binYhigh);

// read in your file     

   ifstream fin("data.dat");

     // while loop to read in file  (checks the input is good )
     // (  x-val    y-val   z-val  )

     double x3 =-999.0;  double y3=-999.0;  double z3 = -999.0;
        while(fin.good()) { 
   fin >> x3 >> y3 >> z3;     
    if( !fin.good()) { break;}  
    // must check if good after reading and before using    
       hist3->Fill( x3 , y3 , z3) ;             
    // Note:  here I just did everything in the while loop 
   }

  TCanvas *c3 = new TCanvas("c3", "c3");

  hist->Draw("CONT4")
```

However unlike other colour plots I've done using this have a colour scale for the height of the z-axis. What do I need to do to get for a CONT plot?

Comment: Have you tried the option `CONT4Z` ?

Answer (score 1):

To get a contour plot with lines (and not colors), you need

```
hist->Draw("CONT1");
```

or

```
hist->Draw("CONT2");
```

instead of

```
hist->Draw("CONT4");
```

See [this](https://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/guides/users-guide/ROOTUsersGuide.html#the-contour-options) for more info on the contour plots.